# How to use Gsuite Relay as SMTP for CiviCRM bulk mailing?

Tags: civimail, smtp, mailserver, g-suite

I have Gsuite email setup with our own domain (name@ourdomain.com). I have tried to use mailgun with gsuite. Although it worked ok ish, as the number of contact increasing, bills are also increasing.

Since there is Gsuite relay service available which allows 10000 emails per day, we would like to setup our CiviCRM with it, so we can use it's full potential.

I have read this post [How to use G Suite / GMail as your CiviMail Provider](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22808/how-to-use-g-suite-gmail-as-your-civimail-provider) but not able to get SMTP working at all from civicrm's side.

We are currently using cpanel hosting and SMTP mailserver already setup on there which allows only 250 emails. Not very efficient and not sure if that causing any issue while setting up gsuite relay.

Did you manage to successfully setup Gsuite and currently using without any issue? If yes, would you please share some thoughts or tips what issue you have encountered and how you have solved it?

EDIT: I have tried to follow the steps as per the instruction on above tutorial and getting this results. I have tried different combination of ports and authentication settings on Gsuite, but no luck. I am using the email with our domain for signin example@ourdomain.com, and app specific Password to set the SMTP

[image: CiviCRM SMTP Settings]

[image: Gsuite Relay service settings]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its been a while - but hope these tips help:

- Make sure you greenlight the IP address of your server for smtp relay.
- Sometimes your webhost will block outgoing smtp ports to servers other than their own. Ask your host to remove this limitation, if they do not, find another host. This is common with shared hosting.
- There are issues with Gsuite smtp relat long term - see this article - it has been suspended - but good to keep in mind. https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/12/less-secure-apps-oauth-google-username-password-incorrect.html

Comment: Thanks. But I should be able to setup with App password, right?

Comment: @Tapash were you able to get this setup? I believe we set ours up simply with the password - not a LSA password. Its been so long - I can't recall.

Comment: no I was not able to set it up with LSA or 2step app password. Not sure what i am doing wrong. Also do I need to necessarily setup the bounced processing and email to email activity processing part to get the smtp relay working?

Comment: Would you please update the tutorial to the latest available resources? I guess things may have changed quite a bit since you have set it up..

Comment: You shouldn't have to - if you send a test email from 
CiviCRM » Administer CiviCRM - System Settings - Outbound Mail
and it works - you should be good.

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: I need to set it up again. I have removed it from my UAT after failing numerous times. I remember vaguely, something like the SMTP authentication failed.  I also couldn’t follow the tutorial exactly because google has changed the UI a bit, so I was going with my common sense.  I will try setting up again and follow up here. Thanks

Comment: Oh that's useful to know about the postponement for LSA / OAUTH2. Thanks @themak. It's a separate topic so sorry doesn't help you Tapash. But for the other topic I've updated https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/mail/-/issues/59.

Comment: @themak I have updated my original post

Comment: @Tapash did you confirm with your host that they are not blocking you from using those ports to reach external smtp servers?
Our settings our similar but we have 
Require TLS encryption: No

Comment: @themak Thanks for your help! It finally boiled down to the host blocking those ports. I am up and running.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a difference between sending via Gsuite and Gsuite SMTP Relay ...

For sending via Gsuite, and comparing the connection details in the post you linked to with a site using this, the difference is that it uses SMTP host `ssl://smtp.gmail.com`

The main practical limitations are the limits and that all mails get sent out with the sender of the Gsuite account, not the address you configure in Civi.

I haven't tried [Gsuite SMTP Relay](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en)