# How to setup bounced processing on CiviCRM for a Gsuite account?

Tags: bounce, mailserver, g-suite

I am trying to setup Gsuite as bounce processing for CiviCRM using this guide https://civicrm.org/blog/dahndy/leveraging-civicrm-email-to-activity-processing-in-gmail

But keep getting the following message when schedule job is ran.  Any idea how to fix it please?

One thing in the log, it says "**webadmin@imap.gmail.com**" but it should have said "**webadmin@our.domain**" as per my sessings below, is that right?

```
Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Fetch Bounces with result: Failure, Error message: Could not connect to MailStore for webadmin@imap.gmail.com
Error message: 

An error occured while sending or receiving mail. Failed to connect to the server: imap.gmail.com:993.
```

[image]

Comment: For username put the full email, webadmin@ourdomain.com

Comment: @Demerit Still no luck. This time it appears like  webadmin@ourdomain.com@imap.gmail.com

Comment: I think that's ok. That message is just outputting a concatenated string, not the actual username it uses to connect (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.25.0/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php#L161). It seems more like it can't reach gmail, so a network issue. If you try telnet from the server can you `telnet imap.gmail.com 993`?

Answer (score 5):

So I just ran into a similar issue. Our bounce handling stopped a few months ago and nobody noticed. We also use GSuite, and our email address appears in a similar fashion in the log. I thought it looked strange at first too, but since we changed nothing and it went from working to not working, I knew that wasn't the issue. I also tried changing the email account password to see if that would fix the problem.

It turned out that Google turned off access for less secure apps automatically, effectively blocking access to the return email account from CiviCRM. As soon as I toggled that switch, bounce handling started working again. This is the link that worked to turn it back on: https://myaccount.google.com/u/5/lesssecureapps?hl=en

Comment: Would you mind sharing your bounced processing settings from civi and gmail please? I have app specific password instead of less secure apps.

Comment: It's been a really long time since we set this up, but I followed the instructions in the CiviMail documentation found here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/#bounce-processing

Comment: From May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.